# How do I write 0-999 using regex?

Tags: regex

I have this regex, see below:

```
/(ANY|1-9|[A-Za-z0-9])/g
```

Is the a way of adding 0-999 in the regex I have already?

Thanks

Comment: What does it suppose to do? `1-9` is literal there - do you want `"0-999"` to be matched as a string?

Comment: Please provide examples of what you are matching now, and what you want to match. Also provide examples of incorrect matches.

Comment: All things are possible, but not are all expedient. This falls into both those categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/^(ANY|1-9|[A-Za-z0-9]|\d{1,3})$/g
```

what exactly do you want to match with ANY and 1-9 ?

Comment: Ok, with \d{1,3} you can match any digit occuring 1 to 3 times, so it will match 0-999, but also 000. If you dont want leading zeros to match it would have to be like that: [1-9]\d{1,2}, the single 0-9 you have already.

Answer (score 2):

```
^(0|[1-9]\d{,2})$
```

If `001` etc. are not allowed (must either be `0` *or* begin with `1-9`)

---

If to be combined with `/(ANY|1-9|[A-Za-z0-9])/g`, you can:

```
/(ANY|1-9|[A-Za-z0-9]|[1-9]\d{1,2})/g
```

(The `0-9` range is already matched in the `[A-Za-z0-9]` part.)

---

**EDIT**
It appears that the shorthand `\d{,2}` is not PCRE compliant. Replace with `\d{0,2}` if using the first (isolated) solution.

Comment: I'd group it: `^(0|[1-9]\d{,2})$`

Comment: @Bart - Does `\d{,2}` work? It isn't working for me in (adobe) flex, ruby and .net (of course, `\d{0,2}` does)

Comment: @Kobi It's (apparently) language-dependent. `{,n}` works in PHP (PCRE, I guess) to name but one.

Comment: @Kobi, @jensgram, yeah, AFAIK, that only works in PHP: it is not a quantifier in PCRE, quote: *"For  example, {,6} is not a quantifier, ..."* see: http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt

Comment: @Bart Kiers Well, after (very little) reflection this seems highly likely to be a "feature" in PHP :)

Comment: Yeah, PHP is one big feature... (although I can't complain, not being exposed to it long enough to form a proper opinion!)

Answer (score 1):

```
/\d?\d?\d/
```

1234567890123456790-

Comment: @Nasir, this might suffice for you, but note that this one accepts strings like `00` and `000`.

Comment: This will allow leading zeros!

Comment: @Aliostad, perhaps Nasir doesn't care about it.

Comment: Well, mine I suppose is safer but more complex.

Comment: @Aliostad, my point is that it might not matter to the one asking the question, so there is no such thing as "safe". Yours as is, is, to be honest, a maintainability nightmare! (it is overly convulsed with all the non-capturing groups and anchors)

Answer (score 0):

In order **not to have leading zeros**:

```
((?:^\d$)|(?:^[1-9]\d$)|(?:^[1-9]\d\d$))
```

Comment: Err, rather verbose... This is equivalent: `^(\d|[1-9]\d?\d)$`

Comment: OK, settle for `^(?:\d|[1-9]\d?\d)$`

Comment: God forbid agreeing with me! :)

Comment: Lols. Yes I like yours is very succint but I hate capturing groups if not intended.

Comment: No problem. :) Everyone's "regex" habits differ: I like mine to be "readable" in the first place (which in my book means, as little clutter as possible). If a readable regex tends to be slow, only then I start adding possessive quantifiers, non-capturing groups, atomic grouping and the likes.